# is the following sequence unbounded or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series

let {$a_n$} be any non constant sequence in $R$ such that $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+a_{n+2}} 2$ for all $n\ge 1$.

then {$a_n$} in unbounded?

i have tried to solve it by taking $a_{n+2}=2a_{n+1}-a_n$ .

then putting n=1,2,3....

i got

$a_3=2a_2-a_1$

$a_4=2a_3-a_2$

...

...

$a_{n-1}=2a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}$

$a_n= 2a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$

adding these i got $a_n=a_{n-1}-a_1+a_2$?

how to go furhter or is there any other method to go for this problem?

Comment: Note that $a_{n}$ is a Arithematic Progression.

Comment: So it seems like a lot depends on the value of $a_2-a_1$. Can you tell me what happens if this number is positive, negative or zero?

Comment: answer is unbounded

Comment: nothing is given further in the problem

Comment: Well, $a_n=0$ satisfies this functional equation and that's not unbounded, right?

Comment: sequence is non constant\]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that according to your condition $a_{n}$ is [Arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression), implying that it is of the from $a_n =a_1+d(n-1)$, which is unbounded, no matter what $a_0$ and $d$ are, so long as $d \neq 0$, which is established in the question.

NOTE: $d=a_2-a_1$

Comment: MXYMXY  thanks. got it

Answer (score 3):

The usual technique for [homogeneous linear recurrence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) works here. You assume a solution of the form $a_n=r^n$ and substitute it into the relation to give the characteristic polynomial.  Here it is $r^2=2r-1$ or $(r-1)^2=0$.  Because of the repeated root, the solution is $a_n=br+cnr=b+cn$  As long as the sequence is not constant, we must have $c \neq 0$ and the sequence will be unbounded.

Comment: thanks i got to know about smething new

Comment: I knew the basic technique before coming here, but I have learned a lot about inhomogeneous ones.  Have fun. It helps if you know some linear algebra-the solutions to a homogeneous equation form a vector space and all your theorems work.